# How to collect data and download files from web link

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a link from where I want to collect the Announcement details and download the attachment using Python.

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/corporates/corporateHome.html'

Open the tab 'Corporate Announcements - Equities'

[image: Link for Collecting data]

I want to collect the data like.

1. Announcement
2. url link for the attachment
3. Download the attachment to local drive

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use Selenium as the data is returned by `requests.get()`. But unfortunately not returned as `application/json`, but rather `text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1`.

However, the data is sent in a json structure, so needed to manipulate the string to be able to read it using `json`. Then you can dump that into a table to have the data.

Then to get the pdfs, just then need to iterate over those links you get with that, and write to disk:

```
import requests
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import bs4


base_url = 'https://www.nseindia.com'
url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/corporates/directLink/latestAnnouncementsCorpHome.jsp'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

jsonStr = response.text.strip()

keys_needing_quotes = ['company:','date:','desc:','link:','symbol:']

for key in keys_needing_quotes:
    jsonStr = jsonStr.replace(key, '"%s":' %(key[:-1]))

data = json.loads(jsonStr)
data = data['rows']

# puts the data into dataframe
df = json_normalize(data)
links = [ base_url + ele['link'] for ele in data ]


for link in links:
    response = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    try:
        pdf_file = base_url + soup.find_all('a', href=True)[0]['href']
    except:
        print ('PDF not found')

    path = 'C:/path/to/file/'
    filename = path + pdf_file.split('/')[-1]

    response = requests.get(pdf_file)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
```

**Output:**

Heres what the dataframe looks like. The PDFs will be written to wherever you choose to put those. Note that some are zip files that contain the pdf. I didn't bother with unzipping those, although you could add that as an additional step before writing (Ie. sudo if file is a zip, unzip it to get the pdf, then write to disk. if file is pdf, just write to disk.)

```
print (df)
                                   company     ...          symbol
0                 RELIANCE CAPITAL LIMITED     ...      RELCAPITAL
1          RELIANCE INFRASTRUCTURE LIMITED     ...        RELINFRA
2                    GRAND FOUNDRY LIMITED     ...      GRANDFONRY
3                    VRL LOGISTICS LIMITED     ...          VRLLOG
4                    GRAND FOUNDRY LIMITED     ...      GRANDFONRY
5   EUROTEX INDUSTRIES AND EXPORTS LIMITED     ...      EUROTEXIND
6                     PSP PROJECTS LIMITED     ...      PSPPROJECT
7                    VRL LOGISTICS LIMITED     ...          VRLLOG
8             THE UGAR SUGAR WORKS LIMITED     ...       UGARSUGAR
9                     ZUARI GLOBAL LIMITED     ...       ZUARIGLOB
10                   VRL LOGISTICS LIMITED     ...          VRLLOG
11                  RUPA & COMPANY LIMITED     ...            RUPA
12                 ANIK INDUSTRIES LIMITED     ...        ANIKINDS
13                 ARROW GREENTECH LIMITED     ...      ARROWGREEN
14       CENTURY PLYBOARDS (INDIA) LIMITED     ...      CENTURYPLY
15                     TARA JEWELS LIMITED     ...      TARAJEWELS
16           INDO COUNT INDUSTRIES LIMITED     ...            ICIL
17         LUMAX AUTO TECHNOLOGIES LIMITED     ...       LUMAXTECH
18                BLISS GVS PHARMA LIMITED     ...        BLISSGVS
19  EUROTEX INDUSTRIES AND EXPORTS LIMITED     ...      EUROTEXIND

[20 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks Sir for the nice help. But how to get the Page2 data ?

Comment: That’s a good question. I would try to answer that for you, but as of this afternoon will be on vacation and away from my computer. I suggest you post that as a new question as you’ll get more exposure than asking in the comments of an answered post.